# How to set varchar on installschemas

Tags: magento-2.1, module, database

I would like to add a new column inside the magento2 database.
Write now i add a `\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT` as the column type. here is my code

```
    if(!$installer->getConnection()->tableColumnExists('review_detail', 'email')) {
        $definition = [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'size' => 255,
            ['nullable' => true, 'length' => 255],
            'comment' => 'User Email'
        ];
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            'review_detail',
            'email',
            $definition
        );
    }
```

right now, when i do my `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` the new column are set as text(65535).

I'm using MySQL as database.  How i can set the new column as VARCHAR(255)? i've looked on several website and everything i see is to use TYPE_TEXT with a size under 255 to setup a VARCHAR.

Comment: provide your complete magento version.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i'm using 2.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it like,

```
if(!$installer->getConnection()->tableColumnExists('review_detail', 'email')) {
        $definition = [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'size' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'length' => 255,
            'comment' => 'User Email'
        ];
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            'review_detail',
            'email',
            $definition
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's worked!! what's the différence between ['nullable' => true, 'length' => 255] and your way?

Comment: @StéphaneBaribeau, With your code, it was creating a sub array withing `definition` array, but if you check the definition of addColumn function, it gets value from `definition` array and not from its sub array. So, you need to add it as your `definition` array element and not its sub array.

Comment: ohh i see!! thanks!